# Is there any online tool to auto-adjust images for colorblind people?

Tags: color

Is there any online tool that can process an image so a colorblind person could distinguish colors on it? Everything Google gave me was colorblind vision simulators, but I actually need the opposite. For example, I've made a map, but some people can't tell some colors apart, so in my case it doesn't have to look «good», it just has to have different colors for those people.